# load the entire webpage article without clicking each section

Tags: windows, website

Is there a way to load an entire webpage article so that I don't have to keep clicking "Next" to read the next portion of the article?

Comment: More information is needed:  What web site?  What browser?  I assume it's a Windows-based browser from the way you tagged the article.

Comment: Browser, chrome. Many web sites have a "Print" button that shows the whole article, rather than having to click the "Next" button to read the next section of the article.  The "Print" button lets me print or save the entire article in one swoop.  It's easier/faster to read the article too.  Kim Komando's site used to have this feature, but doesn't have it anymore.

Comment: You still need to provide a specific URL, I'm not familiar with the site you mentioned, and if it's "many", than a handful would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you'd need to write a user script which visits the URL pointed to the "Next" link, obtains the resulting content from the website, and appends the relevant section of the result DOM to that of the page you're on -- and then repeats that process with the "Next" link in the result DOM, for as many "Next" links as exist. While doable, it'd be a fairly complex piece of code, and would be relatively strongly tied to the structure of a given site; you'd need either to modify it fairly heavily to support each different site, or to build it in a modular fashion such that you could abstract the site-specific parts of it into a configuration object.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes I agree, it would be difficult to write such a script.  I was hoping that there a small app that would aggregate all the "Next" sections of the  article, that is, the multitude of web pages for that article, and show it all on just one page.

Comment: You can try autopager (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autopager-chrome/mmgagnmbebdebebbcleklifnobamjonh) which is fairly configurable.

Comment: @user2313067 That looks like it would do the work, yep.